# 14.04LTS Unity Desktop on my main account not functioning

Tags: unity, gnome

Logging into my usual user account today after updates two days ago (I update regularly), and my desktop opens up, but with no launcher, no control bar, just the desktop shortcuts.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> doesn't work,  can go into **System Settings** via display settings but nothing gives me a working desktop.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> brings up processes window, so I can kill my gnome process, then login with another user account, and everything is normal on the other user account.

I have no idea what's going on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be a window manager issue. Which window manager do you have? Did you change anything recently?

Comment: I only use standard Ubuntu everything.  I don't even know what other window managers you mean?

Comment: Seems like you have some bad configurations in this account. Is resetting unity to the defaults an option to you? If yes, this could help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Comment: Just tried .Rebooted, . downloaded unity-tweak-tool and did reset.  Made no difference.  Also tried stop lightdm and start lightdm.  No difference.   Is there a way I can reset that user account to default values?  I just looked up compiz manager, should I install that?

Answer (score 0):

What worked was to remove the following file for that user account

```
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
```

This put back the launcher and the menu bar in that account. 
I still got a system error report pop up, (the same had popped up once earlier but was unfathomable to me at the time).   In the details was some complaint about libprocps3, so I reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install libprocps3-dev
```

as advised in [this help page](http://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/main/libprocps3-dev/)